# Setting up worklight in apache tomcat and deploy wlapp and adapters

Tags: android, apache, ibm-mobilefirst, tomcat8

I have developed a hybrid application using Eclipse, MobileFirstPlatform Foundation plugin and Apache tomcat 8.

Everything is working fine. I want to deploy this application in AWS having Apache tomcat 8.

How to I set up worklight in Apache tomcat? I need the Mobilefirst console where I can deploy the wlapp and adapters and access my application.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know the Mobilefirst functionality runs as individual enterprise applications running on tomcat. Once you install these on Tomcat running on AWS (which is a perfectly fine scenario too) you will get unique dns supplied by AWS pointing to your Tomcat followed by the MobileFirst context path pointing to your operations console. How you configure tomcat on AWS is a different topic belonging to AWS ?

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas, I believe the IBM mobilefirst server package for tomcat is not free. We need to pay for the same. From where and how do I get the license ?